# Mousewheel - switch between vertical & horizontal scroll until div ended

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

I'm creating a prototype for a vertical and horizontal scroll system.

I would to have an normal vertical scroll of my page until a carousel. When the carousel is at the middle of my page to have an horizontal scroll until the last slide. And after to take back the vertical scroll.

Something like that : https://www.sneakinpeace.com/ but with some content after.

But I have a problem :

- I can not to have the ended of the carousel to continue vertical scroll and remove `.stop-overflow` class

Here's my prototype : https://jsfiddle.net/nx9sraug/1/

To know the end of the carousel I tried to have the width of `.main_wrapper` compared to the width of `.main`, without success

```
if ( $('.main').scrollLeft() == ($('.main .main__wrapper').width() - $('.main').width())) {
    alert('end!');
}
```

What's wrong please ? Can I have some help ?

Here's the full code :

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    init_position();
});

var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
var sliderHeight = jQuery('.main__wrapper').outerHeight(true);
var distance = (windowHeight - sliderHeight) / 2;

function init_position() {
    var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var sliderPosition = $('.main').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

    if (sliderPosition <= distance) {
        console.log('milieu');
        $('html').addClass('stop-overflow');
        if ( $('.main').scrollLeft() == ($('.main .main__wrapper').width() - $('.main').width())) {
            alert('end!');
        }
        init_mousewheel();
    } else {
        $('html').removeClass('stop-overflow');
    }
}

function init_mousewheel() {
    $(document).mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
        $('#main')[0].scrollLeft -= (delta);
    }, { passive: false });
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you to continue to help me. Sorry for the delay. I was working. I look at your code tomorrow in the afternoon and I come back to you. Thanks again !

Comment: I cleaned up the comment section a bit, maybe you could remove those of yours that are out of context now as well... anyway, here's the "final" version - a few optimisations and combining some of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/v3et789k/

Comment: Bonus version where the mousewheel uses the same logic and animation as the keyboard - and some more optimisation: https://jsfiddle.net/fj1dmgn3/

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thank you very much for all your work! This jsffidle v3et789k is perfect but I got a strange "sticky/pin effect" when I scroll in Chrome. Unfortunately the with the jsfiddle fj1dmgn3 the scroll is really slow :-( https://wetransfer.com/downloads/604681defa5c3fdd94bb78747ae69aae20211012112048/cfac4180b3bcfa8b0c49835a88b88c4620211012112106/4292bb

Comment: Repost - fiddle wasn't completely working well. I've tweaked the animations, extending the options with the `easeInSine` type at the bottom which is the nicest curve to start scrolling. You can check out its characteristics [here](https://easings.net). If the animation is already in progress, it will switch to `linear`. That should be the smoothest possible result you could achieve using jQuery. Also improved scrolling towards the area where it approaches the carousel. See if it works better in your opinion, looks pretty smooth to me: https://jsfiddle.net/g8w9a1s6/

Comment: In the last example you can easily disable the animation on `mousewheel` by adding the condition `if (delta) tempo = 0;` to the small list below the variables. Also, you might want to check if this all works correctly on Safari. I read there were some old issues with the scroll position of `documentElement` not being read correctly so the code may need some revision should this still be the case. Although I could not find recent references to it.